# Android App keeps crashing after a certain event

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, registration

I am a new to coding in android. I coded a very simple register and login method.
Every time i try logging in after registering, the app stops working.

My OnClickListener

```
bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            String pass = helper.searchPass(username);
            if(password.equals(pass))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast wrgPass = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and password don't match!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                wrgPass.show();
            }


        }
    });
```

My searchPass method

```
public String searchPass(String username)
{
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select username, password from "+ TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String a,b;
    //a is Username and b is Password
    b = "not found";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            a = cursor.getString(0);
            b = cursor.getString(1);

            if (a.equals(username))
            {
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    return b;

}
```

Also my declaring of SQLite DB

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table " +TABLE_NAME + "("
        + COLUMN_ID +"integer primary key,"
        + COLUMN_NAME + " text,"
        + COLUMN_EMAIL + " text,"
        + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " text,"
        + COLUMN_USERNAME + " text )";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.db = db;

}
```

Stack trace

```
Process: com.example.lenovo.loginappv2, PID: 6022
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: username (code 1): , while compiling: select username, passwordcontacts
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
```

I am unsure of where I went wrong. It would be helpful if explanation could be provided for the solution as I am still very new to Android language.

EDIT: Added Imgur to stackTrace

EDIT 2: Removed Imgur and added first few lines of StackTrace

Comment: add your stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: print your crash log!

Comment: @JJG  I have added the stacktrace

Comment: @SaraTirmizi I have added the stacktrace

Comment: please update your query from `String query = "select username, password"+ TABLE_NAME;` to `String query = "select username , password from "+ TABLE_NAME;`

@Luciferangel update this and let me know!
OR TRY ADDING SPACE after password as it concatinates with TABLE_NAME like this passwordcontacts

Comment: @SaraTirmizi it still doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: @MikeM. I am sorry i will immediately correct it

Comment: @Luciferangel basically error says no such column exists , are you sure there is db having above table and column?

Comment: @SaraTirmizi I created the db using the 3rd block of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query is wrong.

Change it to

```
String theParameter = " WHERE " + "username='" + username + "'";
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + theParameter;
```

This is would be you full method:

```
 public String searchPass(String username)
{
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Sring theParameter = " WHERE " + "username='" + username + "'";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + theParameter;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String a,b;
    //a is Username and b is Password
    b = "not found";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            a = cursor.getString(0);
            b = cursor.getString(1);

            if (a.equals(username))
            {
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    return b;

}
```

Comment: I have changed it and the app still stops

Comment: did you added that column In Data Base?? HAve You Added Column In Table?

Comment: have you Added first.. Any Column In To Data Base Table..?? MAke Sure You Colomn Name Sholud be Correctly Added.

Comment: Its correctly added the error was different this time. it was Activity couldnt start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159474/discussion-between-jjg-and-luciferangel).